# Step into a custom framework when debugging

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, debugging

I have created a custom iOS framework that is added to a project like any built-in framework.

Is it possible to step-into the framework code while debugging? I know we can do that if we add it as a dependent project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug you should add it as a project. Following discussion might help you.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/270461-source-debugging-of-3rd-party-framework.html

Comment: I don't think we should add. Thanks for the link. It explains a lot.